# Dynamic sections with dynamic cells with Core Data?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am really close to the solution, but i cannot figure out the rest, so i am asking for help now...
I use core data, so I'd like to show, whats inside of it.
Here is my code so far:

**at .m**

```
@property NSMutableArray *users, *sharedWishes;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *delegate=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.context=delegate.managedObjectContext;

    self.users=delegate.collectUserNames; //collect every users from database
    self.sharedWishes=[delegate collectSharedWishes]; //collect every wish from DB - each user has different number of records

    [self.tableView reloadData];   
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // works great so far
    return self.users.count;

}

-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    User *user=[self.users objectAtIndex:section]; //shows the username for each section
    if(self.users.count<1)
        return @"no friends";
    else
        return user.userName; //this is just fine, too
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SharedWishes *wish=[self.sharedWishes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //this is where the problem is...the tableview shows the records until the other user records starts

    static NSString *identifier=@"Cell";
    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

...
}
```

So, any suggestion for the  **cellForRowAtIndexPath:**, what should I add? 
Every section should have a title (which has) for the current user name, and every section should contain that particular person's records (which fails). Instead, when new section begins (with new user) the existing records starting to repeat. How should I avoid it?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: added this few line to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
    User *user=[self.users objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    AppDelegate *delegate=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.currentUserWishes=[delegate collectCurrentUserSharedWishes:user];

Now it works!